# Whats the process of Creating a Block on the BlockChain

Tags: blockchain, block, block-header, transaction-selection, mining-technical-details

have been mining on pools and blindly going a long for the ride of

**> generating a block**

Can somebody walk through the process in simple terms of the steps involved in creating a block on the blockchain ?

What determines what transactions get included on the block we are mining ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When miners try to compute a block, they pick all transactions that they want to be added in the block, plus one coinbase (generation) transaction to their address. They may include any transaction they want to form a tree of transactions later hashed into the merkle root and referenced into the block's header.

It is to note that for a block to be accepted by the network it needs to contain only valid transactions: inputs that are not yet spent, inputs that have the valid ammount, signature that verifies ok and etc...

After having a valid merkle root they build the block's header:

- Version (4 bytes)
- Hash of the previous block, thus making a chain of block (32 bytes)
- Merkle root, the tree of transactions' reference (32 bytes)
- Timestamp, number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 (4 bytes)
- Bits, a representation of the networks current difficulty (4 bytes)
- Nonce, incremented when mining (4 bytes)

See more [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm) to learn more on how to build the header.

Then this where your miner enters the game. It starts with the nonce at 0, hash (sha-256 2x) the block's header and then check if the hash in under the [current target](http://blockexplorer.com/q/hextarget) (if you are on a pool the share target). If not it increments the nonce and hash again. If the hash is under the [current target](http://blockexplorer.com/q/hextarget) YOU FOUND A BLOCK, you then transfer your block's header and the associated transactions' tree and the network accepts it. Because you had a coinbase transaction in your block paying to your bitcoin address those bitcoin then becomes yours.

It is to says that finding a block is rare so your miner will eventually run out of nonce to use you can then change parameter in your block header (more likely the timestamp) or add a extra nonce field in your transactions tree thus changing the merkle root.

As for which transactions are chosen to be part of a block, it is mostly the miners choice to include one or other transaction. But normally they would include transaction with a miners fee in it to gain more bitcoin, a miner could also choose not to include any transaction and only get the coinbase one. The propagation of ones transaction through the network also influence which transactions a miner do include.

Comment: How do they select which transactions ?? Is there some tool liek a block chain viewer ??

Comment: Yes there is one http://blockexplorer.com, but actually all nodes on the network are there to relay transaction, miner will include (normally) all transaction they received. All nodes (bitcoin standard client) also has the full blockchain.