# How Mining Reward Goes to Our Wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, mining-reward

Let us consider, if someone found a bitcoin block using his pc, then how he can get reward BTC to his bitcoin wallet?
I really don't know how a miner get reward of 12.5BTC to their bitcoin address. Does bitcoin header address contains miner address? if any one know please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Miner's address is in the coinbase tx that is included in the block. See [Whats the process of Creating a Block on the BlockChain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7330/whats-the-process-of-creating-a-block-on-the-blockchain)