# bitcoin's PoW, real time of creating one block

Tags: difficulty, nonce, block-header

i learn that bitcoin is created every 10 minutes and if block is created faster than 10 minutes, Difficulty will increase.

and study deeper, mining process is finding nonce that start 0 to increase 1 until finding hash value same or small rather than  'Target'

now, 2019-02-14, [Block #562968](https://blockchain.info/block-height/562968?format=json) 's nonce is 3,534,700,356.

it mean according [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/what-is-the-difference-between-kh-s-mh-s-and-gh-s), it calculate 3GHash to create new block.

according to [newest Mining Hardware ASICs](https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/mining/hardware/), it says ASIC miner is calculating 14~16 TH/s. that does not make sense. PoW hash value is calculated 0.001s with this ASIC.

what i missed?

Comment: Related Q: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7330/whats-the-process-of-creating-a-block-on-the-blockchain

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9438.msg136344#msg136344 , same question and detail answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that a given block template will not produce a valid block for **any** nonce value, and so if that happens the miner will adjust some other values in the block template (such as the extranonce, the timestamp, the transaction ordering, etc), and then run through the entire nonce range again, to see if their newly adjusted block template will produce a valid block.

So just looking at the nonce value for a particular block does not tell you how many hashes were performed, it only tells you which nonce produced a valid block for that particular template. Before mining that block, chances are the miner ran through the entire nonce range many, many times, but with slightly different block templates.